# number of zeros of equation $g(x) = 0$

Tags: calculus

if $f(x)$ be non constant thrice differentiable function defined on $(-\infty,\infty)$ such that

$f(x) = f(6-x)$ and $f'(0) = f'(2) = f'(5) =0.$ Determine the minimum number of

zeros of $g(x) = (f''(x))^2+f'(x)f'''(x)$ in $[0,6]$

Attempt: from $f(x) = f(6-x),$ substitute $x\rightarrow x+3$

so $f(3+x) = f(3-x)$ (function $f(x)$ is symmetrical about $x=3$ line)

wan,t be able to go further, could some help me

Comment: Note that $g(x)$ is the derivative of $f'(x)f''(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h(x)=f'(x)f''(x)$.

Now, we can use symmetry to find that $f'(x)$ has a minimum of $7$ solutions in $[0,6]$.

Then, we have that $f''(x)$ has a minimum of $6$ solutions in $[0, 6]$ from [Rolle's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem).

So, we have that there are at least $13$ different solutions to $h(x)=0$.

By [Rolle's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem), we have that $g(x)=h'(x)$ has a minimum of $12$ different solutions.

**EXAMPLE OF SUCH A FUNCTION**

Try $$\cos \pi x$$

We get that $g(x)$ has $12$ different zeroes in $[0,6]$.

Thus, we are done. The answer is $12$.